# DateTime.parse a German date with Umlauts

Tags: ruby, parsing, datetime

Is DateTime.parse broken? I try to parse the date-string `2. März 2015`, which should return the object for March 2nd, 2015.

However, it throws an exception, because of the `ä`-character. Umlaut handling otherwise is fine in my script. What could be the problem?

Comment: It is not just the character. Even if it accepted that character, I don't think it will accept any language other than English.

Comment: Don't easily blame others.

Comment: It does accept other German strings without umlauts. I'm not blaming, I'm asking. :) Please don't downvote if you are not sure.

Comment: You are blaming the Ruby developers.

Comment: @sawa: would posting a bug report to ruby dev list also be blaming? it's just about finding bugs or, in my case, filling the holes in my knowledge. ;) i fully respect and am grateful for what ruby developer community is doing. :)

Comment: Using the word "broken" too easily before making sure it actually is is blaming. You haven't found a bug. You just suspected so without much investigation.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I hereby apologize for my bad choice of words .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What could be the problem?

Ruby only parses English month names.

> It does accept other German strings without umlauts ...

Not really. Ruby detects month names by the first 3 letters and discards the rest:

```
Date.parse('February')  #=> #<Date: 2015-02-01 ...>
Date.parse('Februar')   #=> #<Date: 2015-02-01 ...>
Date.parse('Feb')       #=> #<Date: 2015-02-01 ...>
Date.parse('Febfoobar') #=> #<Date: 2015-02-01 ...>
```

It doesn't work if the first 3 letters don't match:

```
Date.parse('Mai')      #=> ArgumentError: invalid date
Date.parse('Dezember') #=> ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation with the 3 letters.